# push javascript variable into array

Tags: javascript, object, push

I have 2 global variables that I would like to use in place of YYYYYY and XXXXXX but cant seem to figure out how to make it happen. Can anyone offer a suggestion?
Thanks

```
var channelKeys = [];
channelKeys.push({
  channelNumber: YYYYYY,
  name: 'Location1',
  key: 'XXXXXX',
  fieldList: [{
    field: 1,
    axis: 'T'
  }, {
    field: 2,
    axis: 'T'
  }, {
    field: 3,
    axis: 'T'
  }]
});
```

Comment: Which two variables?

Comment: chan1 = 38278 and key1 = BYWPBXO

Comment: chanelNumber: chan1, key: key1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a property to a JavaScript object using a variable as the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/how-do-i-add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name)

Comment: Here's the answer in linked duplicate that is more relevant to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31024830/5894241

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Global Variables:
var var1='test'
var var2='test1'
```

We Can assign the value after intialization of channelKeys like:

```
channelKeys[0].channelNumber=x;
channelKeys[0].key=x;
```

or can be intialized with channelKeys:

```
var channelKeys = [];
channelKeys.push({
  channelNumber: var1,
  name: 'Location1',
  key: var2,
  fieldList: [{
    field: 1,
    axis: 'T'
  }, {
    field: 2,
    axis: 'T'
  }, {
    field: 3,
    axis: 'T'
  }]
});
```

Comment: @frankl, can you try with first with approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can go with below kind of stuff. Are you expecting something else ?

```
var firstVariable = 'YYYYY';
var secondVariable = 'XXXXX';
var channelKeys = [];
channelKeys.push({
  channelNumber: firstVariable,
  name: 'Location1',
  key: secondVariable,
  fieldList: [{
    field: 1,
    axis: 'T'
  }, {
    field: 2,
    axis: 'T'
  }, {
    field: 3,
    axis: 'T'
  }]
});
```

If you are looking to loop in to the array and replace you can use like the below. If both the first and second variables should be array with same length,
You can use the index as [index] near the first and Second variable name.

```
$.each(channelKeys, function(index){
channelKeys[index].channelNumber = firstVariable;
channelKeys[index].key= secondVariable;

});
```

Comment: Those variables dont make it into the array. they come out as the string firstVariable secondVariable

Answer (score 0):

Global variables can be assigned to channelKeys like:

```
var XXXXXX=12;
var YYYYYY =34;

var channelKeys = [];
channelKeys.push({
  channelNumber: YYYYYY,
  name: 'Location1',
  key: XXXXXX,
  fieldList: [{
    field: 1,
    axis: 'T'
  }, {
    field: 2,
    axis: 'T'
  }, {
    field: 3,
    axis: 'T'
  }]
});
```