# How to set properties of an object dynamically in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

SO I have a JS object that looks something like..

```
var Monitor=function(parent,params={}){
    this.parent=null;
    this.canvas=null;
    this.width=600;
    this.height=400;
    this.backColor="#252525";
    this.lineColor="#0171a7";
    this.lineWidth=4;
    this.radius=3;

    /* 2017-12-31 **********************************
    Innitialize the monitor class
    ***********************************************/
    this.init=function(parent,params){
        var that=this;
        this.parent=parent;

        //Loop through params and set them.
        $.each(params,function(i,val){
            eval("that."+i+"="+val);
        })
        return this;
    };

    this.init(parent,params);
}
```

and call it with...

```
mc=new Monitor(
    $("#monitors"),
    {
        "width":800;
        "height":600,
    }
);
```

I want to set the properties dynamically in a loop.

However, to get it to work, I have to use eval (Eval is evil... right?).
So it there a better way to set properties dynamically?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, there's a function for that: check out `$.extend(this, params)` or `Object.assign(this, params)` in vanilla JS (ES6)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a property to a JavaScript object using a variable as the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/how-do-i-add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it like this:

```
 that[i]=val;
```

Here the full working sample:

```js
var Monitor=function(parent,params={}){
    this.parent=null;
    this.canvas=null;
    this.width=600;
    this.height=400;
    this.backColor="#252525";
    this.lineColor="#0171a7";
    this.lineWidth=4;
    this.radius=3;

    /* 2017-12-31 **********************************
    Innitialize the monitor class
    ***********************************************/
    this.init=function(parent,params){
        var that=this;
        this.parent=parent;

        //Loop through params and set them.
        $.each(params,function(i,val){
           // eval("that."+i+"="+val);
          that[i]=val;
        })
        return this;
    };

    this.init(parent,params);
}
 

mc=new Monitor(
    $("#monitors"),
    {
        "width":800,
        "height":600
    }
);
debugger;
console.dir(mc.height);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

An example, I wish that help you, no eval

```
var parent="monitor",
params = {width:600, height:400};

var Monitor = function(parent,params){
    alert(parent);

    for (var key in params) {
        if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        alert(key + " -> " + params[key]);
        }
        }

}

Monitor(parent,params);
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/skppt6go/

Answer (score 0):

create a set of options like this inside your function and merge them with your passed options while creating an object you won't need to loop through each option to set it just use `$.extend` and merge the default options with the passed options via param,

```js
var Monitor = function(params) {
 
  let defaults = {
    parent: null,
    canvas: null,
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    backColor: "#252525",
    lineColor: "#0171a7",
    lineWidth: 4,
    radius: 3
  };

  let options = $.extend({}, defaults, params);

  /* 2017-12-31 **********************************
  Innitialize the monitor class
  ***********************************************/
  this.init = function() {
      console.log(options);    
    return this;
  };

  this.init();
}


mc = new Monitor({
  parent: $("#monitors"),
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```