# javascript function to add key value pair not utilizing second parameter

Tags: javascript, function, object

JavaScript function below does not use the second parameter to update the object.

```
var user11553 = {username:"JStudent01"};
var instagram = "JMann22";
var twitter = "JohnM22";


var updateSocialMedia= (obj,str,str2) => {
  obj.str=str2;
};
updateSocialMedia(user11553,'instagramID',instagram);
```

The output I am getting is `{ username: 'JStudent01', str: 'JMann22' }`
which has added a new key value pair and used the str2 argument but not the str agrgument.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a property to a JavaScript object using a variable as the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
obj[str] = str2
```

it says, let's find the key : str in my map : obj and change the value to str2

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the assignment to the object. You are using: `obj.str=str2;` where `str` is processed as a property of `obj`.

Instead, you want to use the property ***stored*** in `str`. Therefore you should use:

`obj[str]=str2`