# How to combine to arrays?

Tags: javascript

I got item a, which is an javascript object I think?

```
const item = myItem.getAsFile();
```

which returns something like

```
lastModified: 1521979332955
name: "image.png"
size: 15254
type: "image/png"
webkitRelativePath: ""
```

Next I create a object url:

```
const preview = window.URL.createObjectURL(item);
```

which returns `"blob:https://localhost:3000/..."`

Now I want to "push" `preview: "blob:https://localhost:3000/..."` inside my `const item`, so that next to lastModified, name, size, etc. `preview:` will be listed.

How can I do this?

Comment: `item.preview = preview` will work.

Comment: Change `const` to `var` or `let` so you can change item. Then use `item.preview = preview` to add the attribute to the object.

Comment: Where are the arrays advertised in the question title?!

Comment: @Tostifrosti `const` [does not prevent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#Description) the modification of `item`. It just disables storing another value in `item`.

Comment: It is really simple thing, seems it must not be a question.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: @axiac Oh my bad! You apparently need to use Object.freeze() to make the object completely immutable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a property to a JavaScript object using a variable as the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
item.preview = preview;
```

if you don't want to change the origin item, you can use Object.assign

```
let newItem = Object.assign({}, item, {preview: preview})
```