# How to call a function of a module dynamically in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to do something like this.

```
var abc = require('./index')
var x = "someModule";
abc.x.someFunction();
```

So basically I want to do something like this:

```
abc.someModule.someFunction();
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: `abc[x].someFunction()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a property to a JavaScript object using a variable as the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bracket notation

Something like

```
var x = "someModule";
abc[x].someFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var abc = require('./index')
var x = "someModule";
abc.[x].someFunction();
```