# How can I add new property to Object in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an Array of Objects

```
var array = [ {type: 'news', id: 1}, {type: 'contacts', id: 7}, {type: 'messages', id: 11} ]
```

I need a decision that I can add a property and value to an Object. Which to define which object to add a property to, I have a type

Something like

```
function(arr = array, type = 'news', property = 'visibility ', value = 'yes') {

    var obj = arr.find(item => item.type === type)

    /* magic */


    return result


}


result = [ {type: 'news', id: 1, visibility: 'yes'}, {type: 'contacts', id: 7}, {type: 'messages', id: 11} ]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a property to a JavaScript object using a variable as the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that array could contain more than one `object === type`, you can use the function `forEach` and `Object.assing` to set new properties for every matched object.

**This approach mutates the objects from the original array.**

```js
function findNSet(arr, type, property, value) {
  arr.forEach(o => {
    if (o.type === type) Object.assign(o, {[property]: value});
  });
}

let array = [{type: 'news',  id: 1}, {  type: 'contacts',  id: 7}, {  type: 'messages',  id: 11}];

findNSet(array, 'news', 'visibility', 'yes');
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is (if you are OK with mutating the existing object):

`obj[property] = value`

If mutations are not allowed then:

```
function(arr = array, type = 'news', property = 'visibility ', value = 'yes') {
  return arr.map((item) => {
    if(item.type === type) {
      return {...item, [property]: value}
    }
    return item
  })
}
```