# Use parameter in the key object

Tags: javascript

I have something like that:

```
add(messenger) {
  switch (messenger) {
    case 'skype':
      this.messengers = _.assign(this.messengers, {skype: ''})
      break
    case 'telegram':
       this.messengers = _.assign(this.messengers, {telegram: ''})
       break
  }
}
```

But are there ways to make it shorter? Like this:

```
add(messenger) {
  this.messengers = _.assign(this.messengers, {messenger: ''})
},
```

Comment: Use bracket notation: `_.assign(this.messengers, {[messenger]: ''})`.

Comment: Is there no good dupe target for computed properties?

Comment: Maybe: Possible duplicate of [Add a property to a JavaScript object using a variable as the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using ES6, you can do this.

```
add(messenger) {
    this.messengers = _.assign(this.messengers, { [messenger]: '' });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you can set a key to a variable value using square brackets, like so:

```
this.messengers = _.assign(this.messengers, {[messenger]: ''})
```