# JavaScript: Converting a flat array into a tree like structure without using `eval`

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array like this `["aaa","aaa","bbb","ccc"]`.

what I need is convert it into a form like this:

```
{ "aaa" :
  { "aaa" :
    { "bbb" :
      { "ccc" : 1 }
    }
  }
}
```

I know `eval` can do the trick, however is there any prettier solution?

Thank you for reading my post.

Comment: Why would you reach for `eval` to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  maybe I am trapped somehow. In my brain is using pointer which JS doesn't have, or convert it into something like `eval("return ["aaa"]["aaa"]["bbb"]["ccc"]);`. I know this is stupid ...

Comment: @talves I don't think it's a duplicate, I am convert an array into tree, not an object.

Comment: Ok, looks like you are right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Array.reduceRight()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight). On each iteration return an object, with the previous result as the value of the current property:

```js
const arr = ["aaa","aaa","bbb","ccc"]

const result = arr.reduceRight((r, s) => ({ [s]: r }), 1)

console.log(result)
```