# How to add a value and nest an object

Tags: javascript

```js
const arr = [
  [1, "string1", 'string11'],
  [2, "string2", 'string22'],
  [3, "string3", 'string33'],
  [4, "string4", 'string44'],
];
const obj = arr.reduce((acc, val) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < val.length; i += 3) {
    acc[val[i]] = {
      val: val[i + 2]
    }
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(obj);
```

```
output is :
1: Object
val: "string11"
2: Object
val: "string22"
3: Object
val: "string33"
4: Object
val: "string44"
```

I want to replace `val: val[i+2]` to `val[i+1]: val[i+2]` to make the object to be

```
1: Object
"string1": "string11"
2: Object
"string2": "string22"
3: Object
"string3": "string33"
4: Object
"string4": "string44"
```

But this syntax is incorrect `val[i+1]: val[i+2]`, can someone please tell me how to make `val` to be dynamic?

Comment: @CertainPerformance - it's the opposite of that, OP wants a dynamic key when creating the object. I'll dig up the other dupe.

Comment: Real dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [compute name property of ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) to set property name from a variable by simply wrapping with bracket.

```js
const arr = [
  [1, "string1", 'string11'],
  [2, "string2", 'string22'],
  [3, "string3", 'string33'],
  [4, "string4", 'string44'],
];
const obj = arr.reduce((acc, val) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < val.length; i += 3) {
    acc[val[i]] = {
      [val[i + 1]]: val[i + 2]
   //-^^^^^^^^^^^^---- here
    }
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried to wrap them in `{}` but didn't work. The key needs to be wrapped by square brackets `[]`