# Dynamic Match Variable Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript

I want to be able to pass a dynamic BSON variable to match for mongodb.

Here is what I have tried:

```
var query = "\"info.name\": \"ABC\"";
```

and

```
var query = {
    info: {
        name: "ABC"
    }
}
```

Neither of these work when passing variable 'query' to match (like below):

```
$match: {
   query
}
```

but explicitly passing like below does work:

```
$match: {
   "info.name": "ABC"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works when you pass a query object that is like;

```
var query = {
    "info.name": "ABC"
}
```

and passed into the aggregation pipe like so;

```
{ $match: query }
```

You can see its details on [MongoDB Node.js Driver Tutorials](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/tutorials/aggregation/)

---

You cannot use a JSON object to query nested fields, like;

```
var query = {
    info: {
        name: "ABC"
    }
}
```

check [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YNXObr1KefF)

unless `info` contains only `name` field, then it can be used in such a manner. But again you have to pass with `{ $match: query }`, like [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6hgfGuAuJCP)

Answer (score 2):

As [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#query-on-nested-field) says:

> To specify a query condition on fields in an embedded/nested document, use dot notation.

The actual problem is that you have your object property name as a variable in your JS code. Please, check [how to add a property to a JavaScript object using a variable as the name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name).

Here is how you can do it:

```
var propertyName = "info.name"
var query = {}
query[propertyName] = "ABC"
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what went wrong

```
var query = "\"info.name\": \"ABC\"";
{ $match: ""info.name": "ABC"" } // This is single string
```

Here in this query, we get single string that's why not result filter 
But when you are using explicitly passing like this `"info.name": "ABC"` it work

For data

```
{ 
  _id: ObjectId(XXXXXXXXXX),
  info: { name: "ABC" }
}
```

You can use this aggregate query

```
// Create object and use this into [$match][1] stage
   const data = { "info.name": "ABC" };
// Use this object in match stag
         .aggregate([{ $match: data}])
```

if you have array of object then you need to use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)

For data

```
 {  
     _id: ObjectId(XXXXXXXXXX)
     info: [{ name: "ABC" }, { name: "DEF" } ]
}
// use elemMatch if array of object
     .aggregate([{ $match:  { info: { $elemMatch:{ name:  "ABC" }}}}])
```