# immutably update value of a property in array of object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this array of object

```
const d = [{
  a_1: 1,
  b_2: 2
}]
```

How can I update `a_1` value to `2` without creating a temporary variable?

```
const myKey = 'a_1'
const myValue = 2
d.map(obj => ({...obj, obj[myKey]:myValue})) //why this won't work?
```

Comment: I take it `myKey` is dynamic? If so, of course, [Snow's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58155137/157247) is correct, and this is covered by the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name). If it's *not* dynamic, just specify the property directly: `const result = d.map(obj => ({...obj, a_1: 2}));`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder a_1, will be populated to other object, how to avoid that?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what you mean by that...?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm stuck using the logic to update the form's state https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-ives-cx5nx

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `obj` from `obj[myKey]` so that `[myKey]` is correctly seen as a computed property name.

```
const transformedDs = d.map(obj => ({...obj, [myKey]:myValue}))
```

Comment: ...and store the `map` result somewhere.

Comment: imagine I have few input (html), and I use above code, isn't my array will have all the [myKey]?

Comment: @user3106579 Yes, since the key will always exist in the returned object, it'll also always exist in every item in the resulting array

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-ives-cx5nx how do you update the value of this form?

Comment: there's no ```value``` property

Comment: @user3106579 Oh, you want the first (and only) value in the object, so  `value={Object.values(o)[0]` (but I'd consider a different data structure, you currently have `name="[object Object"]` for both inputs too)