# Turn array with two elements into JS object with one k/v-pair

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this array: `["description", "asc"]`

and want to turn it into this object:

`{ "description": "asc" }`

What's the fastest way to achieve this?

I tried

```
const obj =  { array[0] : array[1] }
```

But it doesn't work because I can't seem to set the key of the object dynamically?

Comment: please add more details and maybe a better example

Comment: `const obj =  { [array[0]] : array[1] }`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```js
const array = new Map([
  ["description", "asc"]
]);

const convobj = Object.fromEntries(array);

console.log(convobj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```js
let array = ["description", "asc"];
const obj = { [array[0]]: array[1] };
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
const bar = {
   [array[0]]: array[1]
}
```