# REACT.js variables not accepted in api request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, api-design, react-state

I'm trying to make my code more efficient and reusable by adding variables on my requests and console.log. But for some reason its not working and I can't figure out why! full code can be found at: https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-lake-6h051

This works:

```
  state = {
    lastWeek: '2020-11-09',
    today: '2020-11-12',
    selectedBase: 'USD',
    firstDateValues: null,
    fifthDateValues: null
  };

  getAPI = async() => {
    const START_DATE = this.state.lastWeek;
    const END_DATE = this.state.today;
    const BASE = this.state.selectedBase;
    
    const response = await fixer.get(`?start_at=${START_DATE}&end_at=${END_DATE}&base=${BASE}`, {
    });
    console.log(BASE) ---> output: USD
    console.log(response.data.rates[START_DATE].USD) --> correct data
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
  state = {
    lastWeek: '2020-11-09',
    today: '2020-11-12',
    selectedBase: 'USD',
    firstDateValues: null,
    fifthDateValues: null
  };

  getAPI = async() => {
    const START_DATE = this.state.lastWeek;
    const END_DATE = this.state.today;
    const BASE = this.state.selectedBase;
    
    const response = await fixer.get(`?start_at=${START_DATE}&end_at=${END_DATE}&base=${BASE}`, {
    });
    console.log(BASE) ---> output: USD
    console.log(response.data.rates[START_DATE].BASE) --> output: undefined 
}
```

Why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a property to a JavaScript object using a variable as the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is to change

```
response.data.rates[START_DATE].BASE
```

to

```
esponse.data.rates[START_DATE][BASE]
```

because if you are using `.BASE`, it means `BASE` key, not your key from `BASE` variable