# Use value from one object as key in another

Tags: javascript

This is a homework assignment.

I'm trying to use the value from one object as a key for another.

for example...

```
    const myObj = {
    
    key: "myKey"
    
    }
    
    const myObj2 = {
    
     <--- here i need the value from myObj's key field. So, I thought to put something like myObj.key.value but that 
didnt work so I'm at a loss. I'm fairly new to javascript so this is a little over my head.
    
    }
```

Comment: try something like this `myObj2[myObj.key]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a property to a JavaScript object using a variable as the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const myObj = { key: "myKey" };

const myObj2 = { [myObj.key]: "123" };

console.log(myObj2);
```

Or this:

```js
const myObj = { key: "myKey" };

const myObj2 = {};
myObj2[myObj.key] = "123";

console.log(myObj2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean: put the values from obj 1 to an array .

```
let obj = {de: 80, en: 50, it: 60} => [80,50,60].
```

then you need only: Object.keys(obj)

And you will get:

```
Array(3) [ "de", "en", "it" ]
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to put square brackets around it.