# How to create dynamic object names in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to ask about the NodeJS object(JSON), let see the case.

```
const myname = Date.now();
const scheme = {
  custom_name: value, //the case
};
```

from the example above, what I want is the `custom_name` using the value of `myname`, is that possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: Or check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it is, just use square bracket notation.

Of course, with date the `toString` representation will be used for the key:

```js
const myname = Date.now();
const value = "foo"
const scheme = {
  [myname]: value, //the case
};
console.log(scheme)
```