# How to use the value of a variable as a property of an object?

Tags: javascript, json

In the example below, the object doesn't seem to understand which category is a variable and so it uses as a string:

```js
var categoria = "Carros";
var obj       = {
    categorias: {}
};
obj.categorias = {...obj.categorias, categoria: {}}
console.log(obj.categorias)
```

I want the category property to be named "Cars" and not category. I tried it the way below, but it returns a template string error:

```js
var categoria = "Carros";
var obj       = {
    categorias: {}
};
obj.categorias = {...obj.categorias, `${categoria}`: {}}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name

Comment: you want `[categoria]: {}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a property to a JavaScript object using a variable as the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name)

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use square brackets!

```js
const categoria = "Carros";

const obj = {
  categorias: {}
};

obj.categorias = { ...obj.categorias, [categoria]: {} };

console.log(obj.categorias);
```

Comment: Perfect!
I didn't know about this feature. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. It's a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names)".