# Grunt is failing to build on some valid js syntax

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm working on a legacy project with grunt.  I believe from the *package.json* that the version is `0.4.5` but I don't do too much front end work so may have made a mistake there.

Essentially I'm trying to build a JSON object from JavaScript that has some dynamic key value pairs.

I'm doing this

```
var params = {
    [localObject.propertyValue]: localObject.otherPropertyValue,
    "dateRange": {
        "start": localObject.startPropertyValue,
        "end": localObject.endPropertyValue
    }
}
```

This works perfectly. I post it off to the end point and get the result I want and I've been playing with it all afternoon using

```
grunt --profile=devServer
```

However when I do a `grunt build` I get a failure.  It is around the computed property name - `[localObject.propertyValue]`.  If I leave this out it builds without a problem.

This is the error.  I'm struggling to think if a different way to dynamically add the key and I know no one will want me to update grunt.  I just wondered if anyone could help ?

> ```
> JS_Parse_Error {   message: 'Unexpected token: name
> (scheduleSearchController)',   filename:
> '../../.tmp/concat/js/app.js',   line: 34463,   col: 6,   pos:
> 1254651,   stack:    'Error\n    at new JS_Parse_Error
> (/grunt-contrib-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:196:18)\n  
> at js_error
> (/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:204:11)\n
> at croak
> (/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:674:9)\n
> at token_error
> (/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:682:9)\n
> at unexpected
> (/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:688:9)\n
> at as_property_name
> (/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:1276:13)\n
> at
> /node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:1230:24\n
> at
> /node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:721:24\n
> at expr_atom
> (/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:1181:35)\n
> at maybe_unary
> (/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:1357:19)'
> }
> >> Uglifying source .tmp/concat/js/app.js failed. Warning: Uglification failed.
> ```

Comment: What version of `grunt-contrib-uglify` are you using?

Comment: *"I'm struggling to think if a different way to dynamically add the key"* `params[localObject.propertyValue] = localObject.otherPropertyValue`, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/695050/218196