# Javascript: Using the variable's content as a name

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use the content of a variable as the name of an object property that another function has to save but I can't figure out how to implement it.

```
  function saveData(val) {
    console.log(val); //Here I need to receive the Object in the format of {key Name: value}, but I am getting the name key, as it is not being interpreted.
  }
  const arr = [
    { name: "John", lastname: "Doe" },
    { name: "John2", lastname: "Doe2" }
  ];
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(arr)) {
    saveData({ key: value });
  }
```

I cannot modify `saveData`, so how can I send `{key: value}` in a way that key is interpreted and its content is sent?

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-stitch-32x0t?file=/src/App.js:24-437) you can find the CodeSandBox example

Comment: `saveData({ [key]: value });`

Comment: Did you mean `saveData({ key, value })`? Or `saveData(key, value)`?

Comment: I believe what you actually need is `for (const val of arr) { saveData(val); }`. Do not call `Object.entries` on an array!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a property to a JavaScript object using a variable as the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [initializer notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) for this. It allows you to create "computed properties".

The syntax is `{[variable]: value}`, so your `saveData` call would become `saveData({ [key]: value });`.

Comment: OP already does use object initialiser notation :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use ES6 Computed Property Names:

```js
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(arr)) {
    // You can use any expression inside []
    saveData({ [key]: value });
  }
```