# object.key value is showing undefined in the for in loop?

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

as u can see below , **obj.key** outside the for in loop is working properly but why not in the for in loop ?

and **obj[key]** inside the for in loop is working properly , what`s the reason behind one is working correctly and other one is not ?

**code**

```js
let obj = {
  name: "lucky",
  hobbies: "coding"
}
console.log(obj.name)
for (let key in obj) {
  console.log(obj.key)
}
```

**output**

```
lucky
undefined
undefined
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a property to a JavaScript object using a variable as the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name)

Comment: you should call  same as : `obj[key]`

Comment: @xupitan yeah thats y i mentioned that too , but i am asking why object.key is not working

Comment: Because `key` is not the _name_ of a key and can't be accessed like a named key.

Comment: because you are fetching the property name called 'key' from the object inside the obj variable. While if you want to fetch a property using a dynamic name given from a string you need to use the accessor `[]` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Comment: `key` of `obj.key`  !== `key` of `let key in obj`

Comment: @andy it is  through let key in obj , each time it iterates it assigns keys from the object right

Comment: @ivar that is adding a property right and this is retrieving a property

Comment: @lucky The dot is a property accessor that looks for a literal `key` in your object. Your object contains a `name` and `hobbies` key, not a `key` key. The bracket notation allows you to access a property using a JavaScript value such as the string the `key` variable evaluates to.

Comment: Alternative duplicate: [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Comment: @xupitan why both are not equal xuptian

Comment: Because that's what the JavaScript Language architects decided @lucky. There really isn't much more to it.

Comment: @lucky it's a _variable_ that's been assigned the value of the current key in the iteration. "key" is not a named key in the object and, therefore, you need to use `obj[key]` to access the value. Read that second dupe that @Ivar added.

Comment: you can also call it like this:    eval(`obj.${key}`)    

:))))

Comment: But you shouldn't when there's a far simpler method that doesn't involve `eval`.

Answer (score 1):

For accessing object if you using dot operator then you have to give the key directly and you can not use variable name for that.
eg => obj.name  but you can not use obj.key as it conside key as a key name.
You can user [] operator to access the key in the for loop. Thus your code will be =>

```js
let obj = {
  name: "lucky",
  hobbies: "coding"
}
for (let key in obj) {
  console.log(obj[key])
}
```