# How can I fix this? Can't pass the value of variable into a Javascript dictionary

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, javascript-objects

If you look at the lines that I have commented out, you can understand my issue quicky 
Code:

```
        var x;

        for (var x = 0; x < users['suggestions'].length; x++) {

        var thisUser;
        thisUser = users['suggestions'][x].username;   // Returns the username --> John

        var User = {

            thisUser :                                // The value doesn't get copied here

            {
            'user': users['suggestions'][x].username,
            'bio': users['suggestions'][x].bio,
            'id': users['suggestions'][x].id,
            }
};
            newArray.push(User); 
    }
```

Result:

```
    {
        "thisUser": {
            "user": "John",
            "bio": "Hello, im new!",
            "id": 23
        }
    },
```

I have also tried doing `${thisUser}` but it doesn't seem to work.

This is the result that I'd like to have

```
    {
        "John": {
            "user": "John",
            "bio": "Hello, im new!",
            "id": 23
        }
    },
```

Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name.  `{[thisUser]: { //user data }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using bracket notation:

```js
var User = {}
User[thisUser] = {
      'user': users['suggestions'][x].username,
      'bio': users['suggestions'][x].bio,
      'id': users['suggestions'][x].id,
};
```