# why does syntax error "Property assignment expected.ts(1136)" occur when using backtick in key?

Tags: typescript

When I run this script, `TS1136: Property assignment expected.` error occurs.
How can you fix that ?

here is sample.ts.

```
const str = 'myKey'
const obj = {
    `${str}`: 'myValue',
};
console.log(obj);
```

```
        ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
sample.ts:3:13 - error TS2349: This expression is not callable.
  Type '{}' has no call signatures.

3 const obj = {
              ~
sample.ts:4:15 - error TS2695: Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.

4     `${str}`: 'myValue',
                ~~~~~~~~~
sample.ts:4:5 - error TS1136: Property assignment expected.

4     `${str}`: 'myValue',
      ~~~
sample.ts:4:13 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

4     `${str}`: 'myValue',
              ~
sample.ts:4:15 - error TS1134: Variable declaration expected.

4     `${str}`: 'myValue',
                ~~~~~~~~~
sample.ts:5:1 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

5 };
  ~
```

Of course, this code works well.

```
const obj = {
    'key': 'myValue',
};
console.log(obj);
```

```
{ key: 'myValue' }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a property to a JavaScript object using a variable as the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name)

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap dynamic keys in `[]` to make them work.

```js
const str = 'myKey'
const obj = {
    [`${str}`]: 'myValue',
};
console.log(obj);
```

This is called [Computed Property Names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names)

Comment: I'm confusing backslash. Thank you for your pointing out my mistake.