# How can I access this property in an object

Tags: javascript

I'm returning an object that has a `key` defined like this `template[body]`. Here is an example of the returned object:

```
object = {
 method: 'patch',
 authentication_token: 'a string',
 template[body]: 'another string',
 ...
}
```

How can I access the second value? I'm doing something like `object.template[body]` but I'm getting an error `body is undefined`

Comment: That's... invalid syntax...

Comment: Where is the template & body variable defined?

Comment: I didn't write the code base, I've been trying to look for it but can't find it.

Comment: Check out this example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/pmhxk0e5/

Comment: Does `template[body]` (or `template.body`) point to another dynamic value? While it's possible to use a computed value as an object key, the way you used it isn't a valid syntax. [This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this solution

You can access the value using `object['template[body]']`, like so:

```
let value = object['template[body]'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
console.log(object["template[body]"]);
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you. Slight typo in the solution but I get what you were trying to mean. Thank you.

Comment: Your welcome buddy !!

I have edited typo mistake as well :)