# Is there a way to use template literals in the property name declaration of an object?

Tags: javascript, templates, javascript-objects

I have written a `diagram.appendRichElements` method, that takes an object as argument, like this one :

```js
{
  'polyline':{'id':'polyline-id','stroke':'#fee','stroke-width':'2'},
  'circle':{'id':'circle-id','cx':'10','cy':'10','r':'5','fill':'#fee'}
}
```

I am trying to pass an object as a function argument, I want to transform it to something like :

```js
var diagram.appendRichElements({`${type}`:props});
```

But this kind of code throws an error.

I've tried this code in the Firefox console :

```js
var n = 'test';
console.log({`${n}`:'coucou'});
```

And I got : `Uncaught SyntaxError: expected property name, got '${'`.

Is there a way to build an object using template literal for property name without a `var o={}; o[n] = 'Hi!'` ?

Comment: `console.log({[n]:'coucou'});`

Comment: This question is [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You don't want to use template literals (Y). You just want the key to be dynamically evaluated (X).

Comment: Does this answer your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name

Comment: @samweke yes, and it's already linked as a duplicate

Comment: Maybe my example was not too difficult `${n}`. An alternative syntax has been given, thanks to @rory-mccrossan. @vlaz& @sameweke : it is not only a problem to solve, it is a question to answer. My problems are partially solved, and the question has not been answered at all : Is there a way to use template literals ? With something like `node_${n}`, is there a way ? With a closed topic, it would certainly not be other suggestions, nor answer.

Comment: The duplicate shows you you can evaluate any expression as key. So do that. ``{ [`whatever_${n}`] : "value" }`` Again, you are just blinded by the Y here. Focus on the X - you want *dynamically evaluated*. The duplicate shows you dynamically evaluated. You have almost literally missed the forest for the trees. You were handed what you needed yet still focused on template literals for some reason.